# Can a navigationview communicate with the pages navigated to?

Tags: c#, uwp, navigationview

I'm using a navigationview and want to modify the window navigated to after my settings windows closes.

How can I get the instance of the navigated to page?

If that's not possible, how would I force the page closed so I can open a new instance.  I've set the cache mode to 'required' and have the back button working fine but I can do a 'reload' of everything if needed.  However, the back stack does not seem to include the currently shown page and I can't figure out how to close it.

All pages are opened like this:
    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageA), PageSupportInstance );

The class PageSupportInstance has an update method in it that I would like to call in the ItemInvoked call back.

In my case I have PageA->PageB->PageC.  I can clear the back stack but Page C would still be shown.  Then if I navigate to PageA so it shows the update the back stack looks like this: PageA->PageA.  Not ideal...

Comment: Hey Brian, could you provide a code that you have? It will be easier for community to help you when they see a code sample or the context.

Comment: In my understanding,when you close the setting windows,you want to navigate to a new page(e.g. PageA->PageB,when you close PageB,you want to PageA->PageC? In addtion,Frame.Content method can get the current page).If not,can you provice more information about your exact behavior?

Comment: Updated the question with more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you can't.

Parameters can be passed to the new page so that will have to suffice.  Can be a little klunky but it works.

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later.